# Magnific Popup is behind bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, magnific-popup

I am using Magnific Popup, my images are inside a Bootstrap modal, when I click on an image, Magnific Popup is behind the bootstrap modal, like this:

[image]

How can I position Magnific Popup behind the Bootstrap modal or be able to close the Bootstrap modal after clicking on the image? (It's not the best solution I think)

```
$('.zoom-gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: false,
    closeBtnInside: false,
    autoFocusLast: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
    image: {
        verticalFit: true,
        titleSrc: function (item) {
            return item.el.attr('title') + ' &middot; <a class="image-source-link" href="' + item.el.attr('data-source') + '" target="_blank">image source</a>';
        }
    },
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        duration: 300, // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
        opener: function (element) {
            return element.find('img');
        }
    }
});
```